# Problemas com UTF8 no postgres

Tags: postgresql, jsf-2.2

Tenho um projeto JSF com JPA, banco Postgres 9
A informação com acendo esta sendo gravada com problemas no acento.

> Ex:
>   **ã** grava como **Ã£**
>   **Tubarão** grava como **TubarÃ£o**

O Banco esta com:

> Ecoding = UTF8
>   Collation = Portuguese_Brasil, 1252
>   Character Type = Portuguese_Brasil, 1252

Todas as paginas xhttp com:

```
<h:head>
   <f:facet name="first">
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
   </f:facet>
   ...
```

**Obs:**
Se gravo direto no banco, grava correto e vem correto para pagina, mas quando regravo volta o problema.

O inverso também acontece, digito corretamente na pagina mas quando grava grava com problema.

Comment: Os arquivos foram salvos em UTF8 sem BOM? É um carregamento ajax?

Comment: Desculpe não compreendi o BOM. Acredito que foram salvos sim em UTF8. Quanto ao carregamento ajax hora sim hora não.

Comment: Tem sublimeText ou notepad++ instalado? Abra seus arquivos "java" nele e no rodapé deve aparecer a codificação que foram salvos.... Outra duvida, o problema somente ocorre no momento ajax ou em outro momento ou ambos?

Comment: O problema ocorre no momento da gravação. Persistência.
Os .java foram salvos em UTF8 (visto pelo notepad++)

Comment: Marcelo note que UTF8 é diferente de UTF8 sem BOM, mas ok, vamos prosseguir... muitas coisas parecem ser na gravação, mas o problema geralmente é na exibição mesmo (raramente é na gravação a não ser que você tenha feito algo mirabolante rsrs). Tem um exemplo com mysql que pareceu ser a mesma situação, o usuário acreditava ser no momento de gravar, mas conseguimos detectar que a falha era totalmente na leitura ou codificação dos arquivos. Se puder dar mais detalhes poderemos determinar a origem real do problema.

Comment: Posso sim o que você necessita?

Comment: Marcelo é um pouco complicado de explicar o que é necessário para entender o problema, todavia uma leitura neste link talvez ajude a entender o que pode ajudar a tornar o teu problema mais claro: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Criar um bom exemplo do problema pode ser uma boa maneira de explicar como o processo ocorre até falhar.

Comment: Blz vou dar uma olhada. Só complementando o UTF-8 é sem BOM [agora entendi o tal do BOM :)  ]

Answer (score 1):

Assumindo que a codificação da sua `DATABASE` e do seu servidor estão utilizando o `UTF8` como `ENCODING`, sugiro verificar o seu cliente.

O PostgreSQL possui uma variável de ambiente chamada `CLIENT_ENCODING` que é responsável por controlar a codificação utilizada pelo cliente que está conectado ao servidor de banco de dados.

Com essa variavél configurada adequadamente, o servidor é capaz de converter as codificações do cliente/servidor e servidor/cliente de forma adequada, caso contrário, o caso reportado vir a acontecer.

Com o comando `SHOW`, podemos examinar como essa variável está configurada:

```
SHOW CLIENT_ENCODING;
```

Com o comando `SET`, podemos alterar seu valor, por exemplo:

```
SET CLIENT_ENCODING = 'UTF8';
```

**Atenção:** Uma vez que os dados foram gravados com esse tipo de erro, fica praticamente impossível corrigi-los de forma ortodoxa.

**Referências:**

Portugueŝ (v8.0):
http://pgdocptbr.sourceforge.net/pg80/multibyte.html

Inglês (v9.2):
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/multibyte.html

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Não era isso. 
Tem pagina que grava certo, pagina que grava com o problema.

Comment: Estou verificando mas ainda não encontrei o problema e nem como melhor descreve-lo.

Answer (score 0):

No arquivo glassfish-web.xml que fica na pasta WEB-INF acrescente:

```xml
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
    <parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8"/>
    ...
</glassfish-web-app>
```

Comment: Não tenho esse aquivo.